# Maven versions plugin not putting up last digit only for dependency on use-latest-relases

Tags: java, maven

Hoping you can help me. I'm trying to automate moving the dependency version inside a pom up to the next version based on the last digit.

Eg:

Repostiory has version 1.0.1, 1.0.1.1, 1.0.1.2, 1.0.2

Depdnency inside my pom is 1.0.1.1

The ideal new version would be 1.0.1.2 not 1.0.2

When I run the `mvn versions:use-latest-releases` it is moving my depdency to 1.0.2 instead of 1.0.1.2 as I would expect. Afterall, if I branch to have a new version I don't want to start using the original branch!

After reading about it seems to be because the versions plugin only caters for versions that have 3 segments. Any more segments and it treats it as a string to interpret the version from greatest to smallest. Of course this is correct as "1.0.2" is greater than "1.0.1.2". However, it's not being smart enough to stop before changing to a too high of a number.

Has anyone found a way or a different plugin to overcome this? Sadly our version numbers can get a bit crazy in length (not my choice).

Comment: `use-latest-releases` will always use the latest version, not the next version.

Comment: Continuing @JFabianMeier 's comment, maybe `use-next-releases` or `use-next-versions` does what you want. If not, do consider forking the versions plugin and applying your own version logic. Maven plugins may seem intimidating at first, but they are quite manageable.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Sadly that doesn't do what I was looking for. I may have to write my own plugin but I was hoping to avoid that due to time constraints. Thanks though.

Comment: I would recommend to change your version policy to SemVer... that makes it easier...